# Output Array of Strings onto new range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to grab strings from a specific range of one worksheet and output the array onto another sheets range. Unfortunately the resulting code gives me no output of any sort.

Thank you for the help in advance.

```
Dim strFunds As String
Dim varItemName As Variant
Dim strItemName() As String

Dim iRow As Long
Dim rngMyRange As Range


Sub DataGrab()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Returns").Activate


Set rngMyRange = Range("A5:A100")
varItemName = rngMyRange
ReDim strItemName(LBound(varItemName, 1) To UBound(varItemName, 1))

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

Range("A3:A" & UBound(strItemName) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strItemName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rngArr
    rngArr = Sheets("Returns").Range("A5:B100").Value

    Sheets("Data").Range("A3").Resize(UBound(rngArr) + 1, 2) = rngArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Oops didn't see me how's answer above. This answer is pretty much the same thing.

Try this.

First, change `varItemName` to an array:

```
Dim varItemName() As Variant
```

Then:

```
Sub DataGrab()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Returns").Activate    

Set rngMyRange = Range("A5:A100")
varItemName = rngMyRange.Value
'ReDim strItemName(LBound(varItemName, 1) To UBound(varItemName, 1))

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

Range("A3").Resize(1, UBound(varItemName) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varItemName)

End Sub
```

That is assuming you want to convert your columnar data into a single row. If not, do this on the last line instead:

```
Range("A3").Resize(UBound(varItemName) + 1, 1) = varItemName
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any values to `strItemName`. Here's a version that just keeps everything in `varItemName`.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Returns").Activate

Set rngMyRange = Range("A5:A100")
varItemName = rngMyRange.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, UBound(varItemName))) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varItemName)
```

**UPDATE:** If you don't need to save `varItemName`, you can use this shorter version:

```
Set rngMyRange = Range("A5:A100")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 100)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngMyRange)
```

Comment: I get a runtime error of '13' Type mismatch. I have switched the range A5:A100 to B5:B100 but I'm not sure why this is causing the error.